# Cache large numpy array (or other arrays) into disk to save RAM memory

Tags: caching, buffering, diskcache

I have a algorithm, where I aggregate several large numpy arrays (or other arrays, like tensorflow or pytorch) from several processes into one process. The problem is that those arrays are quite large and often use a lot of RAM memory.

I would like to cache these arrays to disk, but so that I don't lose performance. E.g. by buffering the file ahead by other process/thread.

I've tried `Cache` from `DiskCache` package, but it doesn't help when the objects are very large.